# Комунерос чи комунери

Tags: число

В іспанській мові маємо *комунерос* і однину *[комунеро](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunero)*. Чи правильно буде так і залишити чи перекласти *комунери* і *комунер*?

Comment: Не розумію чому голосувати за закриття. Якщо немає правила, яке вказує на те як робити, то це і може бути відповідь.

Comment: Можливо, тому що таке формулювання питання спонукає до суб'єктивних відповідей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас нема особливої послідовності писати чи ні іншомовні закінчення. Переважно ні. Але винятків багатенько. Наприклад ми пишемо *адвокат* [не *адвокатус*], але *нотаріус* [хоча до кацапів писали *нотар*]. Теж саме стосується запозичень з інших мов. Деколи вживаємо обидві форми, а ля *Ахіл* і *Ахілес*. Деколи це приводить через вплив кацапів до анекдотичних форм на кшталт *бутса*. Щодо Вашого слова. Тут бачу варіанти [наявні на практиці]:

1. передавати як в оригіналі: *комунеро* і *комунерос*, а ля *командо* і *командос*. Це варваризм. І зазвичай ми так не робимо.
2. відсікти закінчення рідні і писати наші: *комунери*. Я не знаю, чи в слові *комунеро*, -о — це закінчення, але загалом не істотно. Якщо закінчення, то *комунер*, якщо ні — то *комунеро*. Для обох форм у множині *комунери*.